# SQL UPDATE using SELECT

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table `t1`:

```
date        |     timestamp
                  2015-02-01 00:00:00
                  2015-02-01 00:00:00
                  2015-02-02 00:00:00
                  2015:02:03 00:00:00
```

I am trying to update the value in date, of just the date from timestamp.

This is what I am using:

```
update t1 set date = (select date(timestamp) from t1);
```

but it sets all values to the same as the 1st row?

Comment: This is a simple and standard UPDATE statement of SQL language. Before asking, it's a good idea to read first the [documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp) about SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `select`:

```
update t1 set date =  date(timestamp);
```

Comment: *head in hands*. Thanks.

Comment: @SMW If this answer resolved your problem, please mark it as accepted, in order to let other users know how to solve the same issue.

Comment: @AlbertoSolano tried when I commented but it wouldn't let me. There's a time delay for some odd reason. Anyway, done now :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use from statement in following manner:

--MS SQL Server

```
Update t1 Set t1.date = date(t2.timestamp) from t1 as t2 where t1.Condintionfield=t2.ConditionField;
```

--SQLITE

```
Update t1 Set t1.date = (select date(t2.timestamp) from t1 as t2 where t2.conditionfield = t1.conditionfield);
```

Hope this helps you.